# Session cookie is too large flask application

Tags: python, session, flask

I'm trying to load certain data using sessions (locally) and it has been working for some time but, now I get the following warning and my data that was loaded through sessions is no longer being loaded.

> The "b'session'" cookie is too large: the value was 13083 bytes but
>   the header required 44 extra bytes. The final size was 13127 bytes but
>   the limitis 4093 bytes. Browsers may silently ignore cookies larger
>   than this.

I have tried using `session.clear()`. I also opened up chrome developer tools and tried deleting the cookies associated with `127.0.0.1:5000`. I have also tried using a different secret key to use with the session.

It would be greatly appreciated if I could get some help on this, since I have been searching for a solution for many hours.

**Edit:**
I am not looking to increase my limit by switching to server-side sessions. Instead, I would like to know how I could clear my client-side session data so I can reuse it.

**Edit #2:**
I figured it out. I forgot that I pushed way more data to my database, so every time a query was performed, the session would fill up immediately.

Comment: What did you store in the session?

Comment: @KlausD. I'm making a movie database system. I want certain queries to be saved for a user's session, so I store my movie models in the session in JSON format.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you are using the client-side type of session that is set by default with Flask which has a limited capacity of 4KB. You can use a server-side type session that will not have this limit, for example, by using a back-end file system (you save the session data in a file system in the server, not in the browser). To do so, set the configuration variable 'SESSION_TYPE' to 'filesystem'.

You can check other alternatives for the 'SESSION_TYPE' variable in the Flask documentation.

Comment: For my current purposes, the 4KB limit is fine for me. Instead of raising my limit, I want to know how I could clear the client-side session data so I can have 4KB of space again.

Comment: I would say 'session.clear()' should do the job, but you mention you have already tried that.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. I even checked if the session had any keys after `session.clear()` and it does not, yet I still get the warning.