# UserWarning: The 'session' cookie is too large: the value was 14773751 bytes but the header required 26 extra bytes

Tags: python, html, dataframe, flask, flask-session

I need to store dataframe in a flask session, i do this :

```
session['pd'] = pd.to_dict()
```

and i have this error :

```
UserWarning: The 'session' cookie is too large: the value was 14773751 bytes but the header required 26 extra bytes. The final size was 14773777 bytes but the limit is 4093 bytes. Browsers may silently ignore cookies larger than this.
samesite=samesite,
```

i add this line :

```
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
```

but nothing change !

how I can solve this problem ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53554226/15011621 maybe a duplicate.

Comment: @charchit i add this line : app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"  but nothing change !

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to reset your session with `session.clear()`? this, combined with `app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"` should do the job.

However, storing a Pandas dataframe into a Flask Session simply isn't feasible. I'd suggest you to have a look at [Flask Session](https://flask-session.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which is an extension that adds support for Server-side Session. If your requirements allow, this might be the way to go.